# Positive operators in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. I am just asking if there's some reference which studies operators $A$ with this property:

$$\left\langle Ax,x\right\rangle  \geq0,$$
for all $x\in H$. And $Ax=0$ whenever

$$\left\langle Ax,x\right\rangle =0.$$

And maybe some applications of these operators on differential equations in Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with complex Hilbert spaces, then the first condition implies the second one. Such operators are called *positive operators* and they are considered in most functional analysis texts and all operator algebras texts.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is positive, then the condition $\langle Ax,x\rangle=0$ implies $Ax=0$.

Indeed, every positive operator $B$ on a Hilbert space admits a unique positive root $\sqrt B$ that satisfies $(\sqrt B)^2=B$. In your case this yields
$$||\sqrt Ax\|^2=\langle \sqrt{A}x,\sqrt{A}x\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle=0.$$
Therefore we have $\sqrt Ax=0$ and finally  $Ax=\sqrt A(\sqrt Ax)=0.$