# Why is square root of hermitian operator on hilbert space unique

Tags: linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

How do I prove that the square root of a Hermitian positive definite operator on a Hilbert space is unique?

I'm specifically interested in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Also, I'm working through a proof of the spectral theorem, so any answers citing the spectral theorem are not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this in an algebraic way we have to consider one possible construction of the square root operator [as for example described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2510561/495075). *The following argument also is taken from Section 104 of the book "Functional Analysis" by Riesz & Nagy (1990, Dover publications).*

Let $T,T_1,T_2\in\mathcal B^+(\mathcal H)$ *(positive semi-definite bounded operators on any Hilbert space $\mathcal H$)* be given such that $T_1^2=T_2^2=T$ and $T_1$ comes from the construction I linked above. We now have to show $T_1=T_2$.

First observe that $T_2$ commutes with $T$ since $T_2T=T_2^3=TT_2$ so $T_2$ commutes with polynomials in $T$ as well as their limits, so in particular $T_1T_2=T_2T_1$ by the construction of $T_1$. This gives us the very important property

$$
(T_1+T_2)(T_1-T_2)=T_1^2+T_1T_2-T_2T_1-T_2^2=T_1^2-T_2^2=T-T=0.
$$

Now let **any** $x\in\mathcal H$ be given. Define $y:=(T_1-T_2)x$ and consider

$$
\langle y,T_1y\rangle+\langle y,T_2y\rangle=\langle y,(T_1+T_2)(T_1-T_2)x\rangle=0
$$

as stated above. This implies

$$
T_1,T_2\geq 0\Rightarrow\langle y,T_1y\rangle,\langle y,T_2y\rangle\geq 0\Rightarrow \langle y,T_1y\rangle=\langle y,T_2y\rangle=0.
$$

Since $T_1,T_2$ are positive semi-definite [that means](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1617297/495075) $T_1y=T_2y=0$. Note that in the answer just linked one only needs the existence of a square root which is secured by $T_1,T_2\geq 0$ - but not its uniqueness (which is important as we're trying to prove exactly that). Now this yields

$$
\Vert (T_1-T_2)x\Vert^2=\langle x,(T_1-T_2)^2x\rangle=\langle x,(T_1-T_2)y\rangle=0
$$

so $T_1x=T_2x$. As $x\in\mathcal H$ was chosen arbitrarily this concludes the proof of the square-root operator being unique.